# How to insert items in a dictionary against their respective keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Have a usecase where I want to add the list items to a dictionary and the list items will be used as a key value pair in the dictionary. For example

Input list and dictionary

`list_Items = [["test1", "test2", "test3"], ["test4", "test5", "test6"]]`

`dict = {"tire1": {}, "tire2": {}}`

Expected output of print(dict)

`{"tire1": {"source": ["test1", "test2", "test3"]}, "tire2": {"source": ["test4", "test5", "test6"]}}`

Thanks

Comment: You've asked several questions, but never give any feedback to answers, nor mark any as accepted? Don't you appreciate the answers?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want a variable called *dict* as that would override the built-in of the same name. Otherwise it's simple:

```
list_items = [["test1", "test2", "test3"], ["test4", "test5", "test6"]]

result = dict()

for i, item in enumerate(list_items, 1):
    result[f'tire{i}'] = {'source': item}

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'tire1': {'source': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']}, 'tire2': {'source': ['test4', 'test5', 'test6']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
d = {}
for i in range(len(list_Items)):
    d["tire{}".format(i+1)] = {"source": list_Items[i]}
```

Note that `dict` itself is a reserved keyword, hence I've used `d` instead.